# How to turn off notifications in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, notifications

How can I turn off notifications that appear in Android Studio at the right upper corner (blue circle with white exclamation mark)? I've googled `"android studio" disable notifications` but it showed me results related to android app development and not to the IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android studio is a fork of **JetBrains** base IDE, there are many IDEs using the same "core", like webstorm, pyCharm...

So for your future searches try **"jetbrains disable notifications".**

You can effectively disable or tweak notifications in *Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Notifications*

Answer (score 1):

In **Preferences**, choose **Appearance & Behavior**

Choose **Notifications**

There are lots of categories and options, I believe the one you're looking for is "Platform and Plugin Updates", but you'll see that you have fine-grained control over many notifications.  Blue circle with white exclamation I believe are those categorized as "Sticky balloon" under popup.